# Fancybox conflicts lavalamp

Tags: jquery, fancybox, lavalamp

i have this page with jQuery LavaLamp 2 and FancyBox 2.
It took me hours to figure out that FancyBox is conflicting with LavaLamp.
When i take out these two includes

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="menu/easing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="menu/jquery.js"></script>
```

The FancyBox works, however LavaLamp doesn't.
Tried to switch the Jqueries ( FancyBox will take LavaLamp  ), didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Here's the fancybox includes:

```
<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="/Include/FancyBox/lib/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script> -->

<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Include/FancyBox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Include/FancyBox/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.0.6"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Include/FancyBox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.6" media="screen" />

<!-- Add Button helper (this is optional) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Include/FancyBox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.2" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Include/FancyBox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.2"></script>

<!-- Add Thumbnail helper (this is optional) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Include/FancyBox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.2" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Include/FancyBox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.2"></script>

<!-- Add Media helper (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Include/FancyBox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.0"></script>
```

EDIT: I have upgraded the easing version, and FancyBox works. However, LavaLamp isn't.

Another EDIT : Mananged to fix the problem. Just downloaded the latest easing.js and easing.compatibility

Comment: Your scripts need to be in the opposite order, jQuery then easing, in reference to your first snippet.

Comment: Didn't think it would matter, but it was. just copied in the wrong order. Sorry.